# Hilla GridFilterColumn

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, hilla

How do I replace the basic input of the Hilla GridFilterColumn component with a Select

```
    <GridFilterColumn autoWidth flexGrow={0} frozen path="type">
      <Select
        items={items}
        value={typeFilterValue}
        onChange={(event) => setTypeFilterValue(event.detail.value)}
      />
    </GridFilterColumn>
```

Not working

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.